# Writing a Makefile for a program that calls exec()

Tags: c, shell, unix, makefile

I would appreciate some help writing a Makefile for a simple shell program that I am writing in C for fun.

The shell is supposed to function as follows. When running the shell, if a user types "my_cat filename.txt" then the program will call execv("./processes/my_cat", "filename.txt"). (The ./processes directory contains several basic programs modeled after standard Unix utilities, such as cat.)

How do I write a Makefile that both compiles my shell program as well as all the utility programs in the ./processes directory (so that they can all be run after a call to execv)?

Here is what I have so far:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall

$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o myshell myshell.o
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c myshell.c

myshell.o:  myshell.c myshell.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c myshell.c

clean:
    $(RM) myshell *.o *~
```

Comment: Create a separate `Makefile` in the `./processes` directory to compile the sources in that directory. Then in your original `Makefile` add as the last line in your rule that compiles your shell `$(MAKE) -C ./processes` to change to the `./processes` directory invoking `make` there.

Comment: Make is pretty smart.  If a file named `foo.c` exists, make has implicit rules which it will use to create foo.  Probably your entire Makefile can be reduced to the single line `all: my_cat my_shell ...`